# excel command(s) to search between 2 different xlsx files

Tags: excel

I have 2 spreadsheets which I will refer to as (spreadsheet 1) and (spreadsheet 2).

I have values under a row called "name" in spreadsheet 1 that I need to cross reference with spreadsheet 2 within 4 of its sheets whether or not those values exists that I referenced in spreadsheet 1 under row "name".

Any help is appreciated,

(spreadsheet1)
(row)
name
1.BAHHBD
2.RTYUWL
3.BKHSLS
4.RIOSLL
5.DKHSLL

(spreadsheet2)
sheet1, sheet2, sheet3, sheet4  <--search all of these sheets for those values in spreadsheet1 under the row "name" and give back a response of true or false if they exist in any of those 4 sheets.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Have you searched SO for similar questions? also add a few lines of the Sheets and your desired outcome.

Comment: so far i have a command like this =IF(ISERROR(MATCH('[C:CMDB.xlsx]Worksheet Sheet1'!A1,'[C:\Migration.xlsx]Worksheet Wave2'!A1)),FALSE,TRUE) but only gives me a True or False for the entire spreadsheet not for every value.  I think im getting close...